# How To Produce 3D Pictures With Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Please I have the python codes shown below, but it does not produce the required plot. The aim is to get something that looks like the expected result. Any help in resolving this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import jv
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

r=np.sqrt (x**2+y**2)
#Calculate the argument of the Bessel function.
theta=k*r/n
# Calculate the Bessel function.
bessel_func=jv(n,theta)
# Calculate the wave amplitude.
bessel_beam =bessel_func*np.exp(1j*(k*z-n*np.arctan2(y,x)))

#Define the x, y, and z ranges.
x_range=np.arange(0,50,100)
y_range=np.arange(0,50,100)
z_range=np.arange(0,10,100)

k=2*np.pi
R=10
n=1

x,y,z=np.meshgrid(x_range,y_range,z_range,indexing="xy")
a=bessel_beam

i_t=np.abs(a)**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, i_t, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

[initial results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A55tu.jpg)
[expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPA0H.png)

I have worked on the codes attached above, and have not yet been able to produce the expected results. I have attached the results of my initial attempts.

Comment: Why are you multiplying `bessel_func` with the exponential term?

Comment: I am multiplying it with the term because it corresponds with the definition of an optical bessel beam. The aim is to use that python code to simulate the bessel beam. An example of the equation is found in Saleh Optics book.

Comment: My bad, I misread that as a "python function".